# Where to put sitemap.xml and robots.txt in case of a Tomcat server with several Webapps

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, sitemap, robots.txt

I have a Tomcat server and several Webapps (webapp1, webapp2, ...).

Where do the `sitemap.xml` and `robots.txt` files should be put?

Do I need one `sitemap.xml` file and one `robots.txt` file for each Webapp?

Shall I put `sitemap.xml` and `robots.txt` under respectively:

`"where_tomcat_is_installed/webapps/webapp1/"`,

`"where_tomcat_is_installed/webapps/webapp2/"`,

...

Shall I disallow `/WEB-INF/lib/`?

If not, is it sufficient to put the following contents into `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
```

Answer (score 4):

`robots.txt` needs to be in the root folder, not nested in some webapp (or multiple of these). It references `sitemap.xml`, so that file has to be whereever `robots.txt` claims it to be. No robot will ever check for `/some/path/to/robots.txt`, they'll only go for `robots.txt`

If you have multiple webapps on one server, you'll have to combine their individual configurations in a single robots/sitemap (well, single for each) file.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Given what I wrote earlier, is "where_tomcat_is_installed/webapps/" the root folder?

Comment: As the root folder technically would have no name (but it's not `webapps/` itself), tomcat names it ROOT by default (note the capital letters). Alternatively, if you have a context.xml file, you can also use this to declare that a webapplication should be deployed as "/". But, instead of learning about context.xml files just for this purpose, `webapps/ROOT` is fine as well.